# Vue component data property not updating after parent data changes

Tags: vue.js

I have a vue component (card-motor) with a prop named motor:

```
    <div v-for="chunk in chunkDataMotores" class="row">
      <div v-for="motor in chunk" class="col-md-6">
          <card-motor :motor="motor"></card-motor>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Whenever data (motor) changes on the parent, the changes on the data property (id_color, id_motor, nombre _motor, etc...) of the component does not get updated. Here the card-motor component:

```
<template>
<div class="card" :data-motor-id="id_motor">
    <div class="card-header" :style="backgroundColor">
        <h4 class="text-center">{{nombre_motor}}<button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm pull-right" :data-motor-id="id_motor" @click="show_modal_colores(id_motor)">Color motor</button></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <div class="mb-0">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" :href="computedId">
                        Piezas asociadas {{nombre_motor}}  <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                    <button @click="addPieza(id_motor)" class="btn pull-right" title="Añadir pieza nueva al motor"><i class="fa fa-plus text-info" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div :id="id_motor" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item" v-for="pieza in piezas_motor">
                            <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{nombre_motor}}</span> {{pieza.pieza}}
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['motor'],
    data: function () {
        return {

            nombre_motor: this.motor.motor,
            id_motor: this.motor.id,
            id_color: this.motor.color.id,
            piezas_motor: this.motor.piezas,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        show_modal_colores: function(id){
            let $engine = $('#engine-colors');
            $engine.data('motor-id', id);
            $engine.find('div.color').removeClass('active');
            $engine.find('div[data-id="'+this.activeColor+'"]').addClass('active');
            $engine.modal('show');
        },
        addPieza(id) {
            let $form = $('#form-pieza');
            $form.data('motor-id', id);
            $form.modal('show');
        }
    },
    computed: {
        computedId: function () {
            return '#'+ this.id_motor;
        },
        backgroundColor: function () {
            return 'background-color: '+ this.motor.color.codigo;
        },
        activeColor: function () {
            return this.motor.color.id;
        }
    },
}
```

And here the parent code (root component):

```
Vue.component('card-motor', require('./components/CardMotor.vue'));

var app = new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        dataMotores: [],
        dataPuestos: [],
        background_style: {
            'background-color': ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        makeActiveColor: function(e) {
            $(e.currentTarget).closest('.modal-body').find('div.color').removeClass('active');
            $(e.currentTarget).closest('div.color').addClass('active');
        },
        changeColor: function(e) {
            let vm = this;
            let id=$(e.currentTarget).closest('div.modal-content').find('.active').data('id');
            let motor_id = $(e.currentTarget).closest('#engine-colors').data('motor-id');
            axios.post('/admin/motores/change-color', {idmotor:motor_id, idcolor: id})
                .then(response=>{
                    this.getData();
                    $('#engine-colors').modal('hide');

            });
    },
    getData: function(){
        axios.get('/admin/motores/api/data')
            .then(response => {
                this.dataMotores = response.data.motores;
                this.dataPuestos = response.data.puestos;
            })
            .catch();
    }
},

computed: {
  chunkDataMotores() {
        return _.chunk(this.dataMotores, 2);
    }
},

created: function() {
    this.getData();

    }
});
```

Data returned from the axios call to the server are arrays of objects (getData method). Computed properties updates properly on the component, but not the data property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making copies of your props, so the component renders, make your copies inside data(), but data() is called once, so when the parent component updates the child does not update.

```
data: function () {
    return {
        nombre_motor: this.motor.motor,
        id_motor: this.motor.id,
        id_color: this.motor.color.id,
        piezas_motor: this.motor.piezas,
    }
},
```

You can use motors prop directly, like:

```
<div class="card-header" :style="backgroundColor">
  <h4 class="text-center">
    {{ motor.motor }}
    <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm pull-right"
      :data-motor-id="motor.id" 
      @click="show_modal_colores(motor.id)">
      Color motor
    </button>
  </h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass value of `dataMotores` in components

```
      <card-motor :motor="dataMotores"></card-motor>
```